# How can I implement different travel types with google directions api for an android app?

Tags: android, api, routes, maps, distance

I already implemented the basic route between 2 points, but I want to be able to choose if I want to display a driving route or a bicycle route. 
Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add `&mode=yourmode` at the end of the URL.
For Example : `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&mode=bicycling&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

You can find every Travel mode [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=en#TravelModes)